# Defining a public library interface in Java

Tags: java, libraries

What are the options to define the public interface to a library in Java.

For example I often find that things are public because another package in the library needs them (although still with a common base package, e.g. com.stackoverflow.mylib.), so they can't have the package access level, and generally people don't want massive packages (it also seems that people using Spring insist on having the separate controller/service/model/impl/etc. packages, resulting in a single "feature" being forced to span many packages, when say a given service might be a completely internal implementation detail not for external use...).

So the ideal goal is to make the Jar I provided to 3rd parties to make it clear that these things are not to be used, ideally by not having them available at all (not present in the API jar), so that it is not possible for them to use and compile with those internal objects/methods.

Even more ideally for objects there only supposed to obtain from some kind of factory (e.g. a provided Spring Bean), a way to prevent direct instantiation from their code or custom bean (which may leave some future, not yet present property uninitialised after upgrade).

The two formal ways I know of currently are:

- In some projects I have worked on, there is an api package (e.g. com.stackoverflow.mylib.api), and the rule is only the contents of this package may be directly accessed by outside users.
- In some other projects I have worked on, there have been some custom attributes, e.g. @PublicSDK to mark objects and methods for use by the public (and I think some extra stuff to ensure only things marked as such are in the publicly distributed javadoc and api jar).

Comment: Leave a comment or make/suggest an edit dont just close-vote... I want to know what the technical options are (i.e. list with any relevant pro's con's) for the given sort of situation (library code).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to ask yourself is - *do you really need to hide the implementation details*?

The reason I say this is that there's going to be an expense involved in doing so, which depending on your circumstances may or may not be worth paying.

For example, if your API is being used by developers outside of your immediate team then it's probably worth the expense; however if it's just to hide the implementation details within you team I think it's overkill.

If the API is for use within your project then a standard where by you try to depend only on abstract types or interfaces is, imho, sufficient (and already the standard).

However, assuming you do need to hide the implementation and expose only the public API, the best way I know to do it is to produce two jars - one containing the public API and another that is the implementation of that API.

If you're using Maven or Gradle to build the project that is using your API you simply declare a compile time dependency on the API jar (artifact) and a runtime dependency on the implementation jar (artifact).

This pattern can be seen throughout the common Java APIs, the latest example being the [JSON API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html) that is implemented separately as part of Glassfish.

Comment: In my experience yes, for common modules going to several other teams (or the public), and generally people code to what the IDE says, which has a doc (that they likely didn't really read) and shows it as public (so no compile warning/error either for them). Then they refuse/dont have resources to change it so get stuck supporting the behaviour of this internal thing (since that jar needs to be backwards compatible to a large degree to prevent difficult upgrade situations on the customers server)...

Comment: So how are the two jar's produced? This is sounding a lot like my second method (using an attribute to strip things out of the API jar)

Comment: Simple, two projects - one to produce the public API, another to produce the implementation.  And avoid the temptation to use a multi-module pom if you're using Maven - you'll lock yourself into releasing the public API with each release of the implementation, which is a pain when trying to do bug-fix releases of just the implementation

Comment: So more like option 1? Theres a set of API classes that provide a thin wrapper around the implementation classes?